# Custom Post Type Link from Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm currently working on a plugin that creates a custom post type.  The issue I'm strugging with at the moment is that the custom post type is created fine, but when I go to add a new post I receive an "Invalid Post Type" error.

The ui is hidden and I'm trying to link to it from add_submenu_page.  I need assistance for how to properly link it.

Here is what I have in the submenu declaration:

```
add_submenu_page( 'restaurant-orders', 'Menu Management', 'Menu Management', 'manage_options', 'edit.php?post_type=menu-item');
```

My post type:

```
function restaurant_menu_items() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Restaurant Menu Items', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => __('Restaurant Menu Item', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'product page'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Menu Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Menu Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New Menu Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View Menu Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Menu Items'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
      ); 

    register_post_type( 'menu-item' , $args );
}
```

I can add a new post if I show the ui and do it the conventional way. However I do not want it this way, the post menu has to be under the plugin menu.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magic here is:

```
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => 'plugins.php',
```

Try this:

```
function restaurant_menu_items() {

    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Restaurant Menu Items', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => __('Restaurant Menu Item', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'product page'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Menu Item'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Menu Item'),
        'new_item' => __('New Menu Item'),
        'view_item' => __('View Menu Item'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Menu Items'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => 'plugins.php',
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/article16.png',
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
      ); 

    register_post_type( 'menu-item' , $args );
}
```

Comment: +1 Please elaborate _why_ this is the solution. I've written an answer to extend yours, but left this part out.

Comment: Dude this explanation is totally unnecessary in my opinion.Who wants more options like this , can read codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type We dont need to complicate things for new starters imo

Comment: The Codex is _incomplete_ and a mess and often just wrong or outdated. On the other hand point is that not only _starters_ stumble about those arguments.

Comment: We must encourage people to use codex. If you believe codex info is outdated or wrong, you can always update it with your wordpress.org account. It will help much more to community rather to share detailed answer on 3th party site's question/answer.

Comment: I don't want a comment explosion here, so we'll have to end it. [You can view my hundreds](http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Special:Contributions&limit=500&target=F+J+Kaiser) of additions to Codex, but I don't think that Codex is meant to explain each and everything. Codex is basic information and WPSE is specific layer _on top of it_ that shows edge scenarios and offers more detail.

Comment: Seeing a practical example is what helped me the most.  I'm not "new" to plugin development, but this is the first time I'm attempting a link in this manner.  Thank you all!

The one change I made was to change 'show_in_menu' so that the custom post type was inside my plugin menu and not the Plugins menu.

Comment: ["Basically, a code-only answer doesn't help other visitors learn. It doesn't help _anyone_ learn. That doesn't make the Internet Better™, that just helps us degrade into a quick-fix forum."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134369/185667)

Answer (score 3):

As **@ÜnsalKorkmaz** already pointed out in his *solution*, one needs to use `show_in_menu`. I'm trying to explain what the problem with `NULL` or `FALSE` values is, when you're registering a custom post type or a custom taxonomy: There're **defaults** that you have to know... or have to know how to get enough **feedback** to understand what happens.

### Inspect core

Take a look at `register_post_type()` internals. In the following example, which is taken from that API function, you'll see what happens.

```
// If not set, default to the setting for public.
if ( null === $args->show_ui )
    $args->show_ui = $args->public;

// If not set, default to the setting for show_ui.
if ( null === $args->show_in_menu || ! $args->show_ui )
    $args->show_in_menu = $args->show_ui;
```

### Conclusions you can make after reading core internals

Most core functions have a default value that makes work even if you don't specify every value. And some of those parameters have a *lower* priority as others. You can see that with the `public` argument that will have a default only if `show_ui` was *not* defined.

### How to gather enough feedback?

Most core functions have a hook to intercept the arguments and that runs before the actual task as well as another one that runs immediately afterwards. In this situation the *later* hook looks like this:

```
do_action( 'registered_post_type', $post_type, $args );
```

So you make yourself a little…

### …plugin that helps you doing live debugging

This will now output/dump the full set of arguments, **after** core has thrown in its defaults. From my own experience: This is a massive helper as you can monitor every single change without getting down the rabbit hole and making your hands dirty in core. Enjoy.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#89066) Debug Register Post Type Args
 */
add_action( 'registered_post_type', 'wpse89066_debug_cpt_args', 10, 2 );
function wpse89066_debug_cpt_args( $post_type, $args )
{
    printf( '<h1>%s</h1>', $post_type );
    var_dump( $args );
}
```

### Full Plugin

You can grab the full version of this plugin [over here at GitHub as Gist](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/5070778).

Comment: Small hint. The Plugin Debug Objects (currently only the [git version](https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects), is not released in sv n of wp.org) list the arguments for custom post types, same topic.

Comment: @bueltge Nice. Didn't know about this one. Should be a separate answer. I'm now reverting your edit as my plugin simply isn't yours and the output you added would raise the wrong expectations :)

Comment: Ok, I have think, it is the same output, only the change on style.

Answer (score 2):

The helper plugin for developer *[Debug Objects](https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects)* list the arguments of custom post types, easy to use. But for this output part use the current development version on github, she have more features.

Example output of arguments to custom post type.
[image]

Comment: Nice plugin +1 for this .